# Norton Security disables Windows Firewall

Tags: anti-virus

I want to re enable windows firewall but Norton also seems to have disabled the firewall control panel button " turn windows firewall on or off." What do I do?

Comment: My recommendation? Uninstall Norton (in)security, and all other similar malware.

Comment: Norton has a built-in firewall and you should use it instead of the Windows firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I know no way of enabling the Windows Firewall, unless you uninstall Norton Internet Security.  This question arises with many third-party firewalls, so if there were a viable way of doing this, I'm sure it could be found easly in a web search.

"Reach out to [Norton Cust Support](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/norton-internet-security/20.4.0.40/contact?actstat=activated&buildname=Retail&conntype=100000000&coreservice=Startup%20Type%3Aauto%20State%3ARunning&cpu=x86%20Family%206%20Model%2015%20Stepping%2013&curdefs=20130713.006&datetime=07-14-2013%2020%3A27%3A03%20PM%20GMT&defbrowser=Firefox&dsfree=64.02&dstotal=116.98&endpointid=%7Bd88063de-74fb-467c-8fa4-37f53c45173d%7D&entsrc=Direct_Selfheal&env=prod&hbguid=d88063de-74fb-467c-8fa4-37f53c45173d&hcmode=false&heartbeatID=d88063de-74fb-467c-8fa4-37f53c45173d&ieversion=9.0.8112.16421&layout=Retail&layouttype=ESD&lic_attr=21124114&lic_type=16&memload=52&memtotal=2603&os=windows&oslang=iso%3AENG&oslocale=iso%3AUSA&osvers=6.0&osversion=6.0%206002.18832.x86fre.vistasp2_gdr.130501-1537&partnerid=&partnername=Retail&plang=sym%3AEN&plgid=2&plid=2&psn=XKQCMBX76CWJ&remdays=147&sessionid=%7B326C942D-A1AF-415B-A5AB-0C2A8A1A88E8%7D&skuf=21228659&skum=21234721&skup=21234720&spversion=2.0&sublength=160&subremaining=147&substatus=current&symskucurrent=21234720&symskumedia=21234721&utm_medium=product&utm_source=symc&vendorid=) re changing your Norton product from NIS to NAV"